# how to fix npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...m":"b569e8103ed5b2ad3'

Tags: node.js, npm

When i was installing electron

I used the command as in the docs

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...m":"b569e8103ed5b2ad3'
```

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-12T04_21_01_515Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Powershell as admin

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install electron --save-dev
```